# Get count of array objects belonging to a partical ID in JavaScript/Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
var array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
]
```

The ID's in the above array (2,3 and 4) come dynamically from a server response.
I need to count the number of entries for a particular ID.
I'm not able to figure out how to loop over this array to get the expected output.
The expected output is:

```
[{"ID" : "4", Count : "1"},{"ID" : "3", Count : "2"},{"ID" : "2",Count : "3"}]
```

Note that the output is in the ascending order of the Count.

This is what I tried :

```
var temp1 = [];
                var temp2 = [];
                var temp3 = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
                     if(array[i][0] == 2){
                        temp1.push(array[i])
                     }
                     if(array[i][0] == 1){
                        temp2.push(array[i])
                     }
                     if(array[i][0] == 3){
                        temp3.push(array[i])
                     }

                }

 var output = [{
                    ID: "2",
                    Count: temp1.length,
                },
                {
                    ID: "1",
                    Count: temp2.length,
                },
                {
                    ID: "3",
                    Count: temp3.length
                }]

console.log(output)
```

I believe the way I'm doing it is not the best approach if the data is dynamic.
How do I do it in a better way?

Comment: I'm updating the question please check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combined use of [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will yield this:

```js
const array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
];

const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, [id]) => {
  a[id] = (a[id] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {})).map(([ID, Count]) => ({ID, Count}))
       .sort((a, b) => a.Count - b.Count);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you suggest me some good resources to read so that I can tackle such tricky situations myself

Comment: can you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493692/node-js-promise-inside-for-loop-always-prints-promise-pending

Answer (score 1):

You could use map and filter to transform the array and count the ocurrences, then you sort the array by the count property:

```js
const array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
];

const result = [];
array.forEach( item => {
  if (result.find( id => item[0] === id["ID"])){
    return;
  }
  result.push({"ID": item[0], Count: array.filter(ids =>  ids[0] === item[0]).length});
})

// And then sort it
result.sort( (a,b) => a.Count - b.Count);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
var array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
];

var y = {};
var z = [];
array.forEach(x=>{      //creating object which will store freq of Id
  if(!y[x[0]]){
    y[x[0]] = 0;
  }
  y[x[0]]++;
});
Object.keys(y).forEach(x=>{   //converting above object to array
  z.push({'ID': x, 'Count':y[x]});
});
console.log(z.sort((a,b) => a.Count - b.Count))//sorting array as per requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
];

const res = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 let foundElement = acc.find(x => x.id === curr[0]);
 
 if (!foundElement) {
  foundElement = {
   id: curr[0],
   count: 1
  };
  
  acc.push(foundElement);
 }
 else {
  foundElement.count += 1; 
 }
 
 return acc;
}, [])
.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your `for` loop an easy way is to check for each item if it's already included in the output, and if so to increment the count, as such:

```
var array = [
[ '2','Yes'],
[ '2','Yes'],
[ '2','Yes'],
[ '3','Yes'],
[ '3','Yes'],
[ '4','Yes'],
];

var output = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if(!output.find(item => item.ID === array[i][0])){
    output.push({'ID': array[i][0], 'Count': 1});
  } else {
    output.find(item => item.ID === array[i][0]).Count += 1;
  }
}
output.sort( (a,b) => a.Count - b.Count)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I also thought that the output was just reversed initially, but it's actually sorted by `Count`, according to the question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen absolutely right I missed this, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intended result with the below piece of code as well.

```
var array = [ 
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '2','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '3','Yes'],
    [ '4','Yes'],
]

var arrMap = {}

array.map(item => {
    if(arrMap[item[0]]){
     arrMap[item[0]]++ 
    }else{
     arrMap[item[0]] = 1
    } 
})

var resultArr = []

for(var keys of Object.keys(arrMap)){
 resultArr.push({"ID":keys,"Count":arrMap[keys]})
}
```